How to get data produced by worker_status.py on Dataflow?
I have a pipeline built with the Python SDK running on Dataflow using the Streaming Engine.
I noticed in the beam sources that apache_beam/runners/worker/worker_status.py exposes plenty of diagnostics that I would be very much interested in:

thread dump
heap dump
state cache stats
active processing bundle state

I'd love to see this information, but I haven't found anything on how to enable these Worker Status metrics and then access them via an external client.

thread/heap dump info is only enabled if you've enabled cloud profiler - https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/docs/guides/profiling-a-pipeline - once collected, you should be able to download it following this guide - https://cloud.google.com/profiler/docs/downloading-profiles
For the rest, Dataflow is integrated with cloud monitoring - https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/docs/guides/using-cloud-monitoring - and you should be able to export metrics as needed by following https://cloud.google.com/architecture/monitoring-metric-export
